# Determining whether a function is injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Question:

Let f : $\mathbb{R}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ via $ f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$. Is $f$ injective?

My attempt:

I am unable to find a counter example to prove that it is not injective.

Suppose $ f(a) = f(b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

$ \frac{a}{1+a^2}=\frac{b}{1+b^2}$

$a\ +\ ab^2\ =\ b\ +ba^2$

$ ab^2-b\ \ =ba^2-a$

$ b\left(ab-1\right)=a\left(ab-1\right)$

$ \left(b-a\right)\left(ab-1\right)=0$

Would this imply that $ a = b$? In questions where I cannot easily figure out a counter example to prove a function is not injective, what should I do? Should I try to prove that it is injective and then reach a contradiction?

Comment: No, you got the correct answer: when $ab=1$. So $f(a)=f(1/a)$

Comment: You 've practically found the counteraxample : to have $(ab-1)=0$ we need $a=1/b$. So, take for example $a=3$ and $b=1/3$ and check that $f(3)=f(1/3)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It cannot be injective since $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}$ implies $f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for any $x\in(0,1)$, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Following your own computations, assuming continuity throughout the answer, the condition $(a-b)(ab-1)=0$ means equality is reached either when $a=b$ ( tautological) , or when $b=1/a$. Double-checking ( assume $a \neq 0$, which anyway does not satisfy $ab=1$):

$$ f(a):= \frac {a}{1+a^2}; f(1/a):= \frac {1/a}{1+(1/a)^2}=\frac {1/a}{(a^2+1)/a^2}=\frac {a}{1+a^2} $$ ( after cancelling the a's). Notice that for a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ to be injective , it must be monotone, EDIT : for surjectivity, we must have  $Lim f(x)_{x \rightarrow \infty} =\infty $ and $Lim f(x)_{x \rightarrow - \infty} = - \infty$ , or change the order of the infinities.

Comment: $\tanh(x)$ is injective, the limits do not need to be infinite.

Comment: @Zwim :Ah, yes, I was thinking surjective. Let me edit.

Comment: "Notice that for a function ... to be injective, it must be monotone" -- not true. This statement is true for continuous functions, but not in general.

Comment: @gary: Likewise, the part about surjectivity also requires continuity.altogether.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: What do you mean, that the condition does not apply to discontinuous functions? I guess in order to apply the IVT?

Comment: @gary: Yes, a discontinuous function can be surjective without having infinite limits at infinity. Examples are easy but for example, $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$. Also, please ignore the word "altogether" in my previous comment, it was written there erroneously.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: Don't we assume we are working with continuous functions? It seems few reasonable things can be said otherwise.

Comment: @gary: No, why should we assume that? Not all functions are continuous (in fact, most aren't). Your statement "for a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be injective it must be monotone" is false. Your statement "For $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to be surjective, we must have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty, \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ or vice versa" is also false. All else being equal, it's better to make true statements than false ones. Both statements would become true if you added the condition that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: What I meant is that , since few statements can be reasonably made about collections of functions that are not continuous, so we assume, AFAIK, that the functions mentioned are continuous; wouldn't you agree? Still, I will edit.

Comment: @gary: I don't agree. If being continuous is a requirement to what we're saying, we're supposed to state this explicitly.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld: I don't fully agree with you, but I added the condition in an edit. My point is, it is known that not much meaningful can be said about non-continuous functions, so when something non-trivial  is said about functions, it is assumed they are continuous. Still, I Edited in the condition of continuity at the beginning. EDIT : This may be similar toassuming sets you are working with are non-empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62336/discussion-between-meni-rosenfeld-and-gary).

Answer (score 2):

A function which is continuous and injective should be strictly monotonic

[else we can invoke the intermediate value theorem before and after any local extremum and find duplicated values]

Here since $1+x^2\neq 0$ then $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$.
Yet $f(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

Since $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$ then $f$ cannot be strictly monotonic and furthermore injective.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous function $f$ defined on $\Bbb R$ satisfies
$f(0) = 0$
$f(1) = 1/2$

By the intermediate value theorem, 
$\tag 1 f(\alpha) = 1/4$ for some $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$.

Also
$f(1) = 1/2$
$f(10) = 10/101$

By the intermediate value theorem, 
$\tag 2 f(\beta) = 1/4$ for some $1 \lt \beta \lt 10$

By (1) and (2) the function can't be injective.

If you are not familiar with the intermediate value theorem, sketch a rough graph. You might convince yourself that, say, $f(x) = 1/4$ has two solutions.
Solving for $x$,

$\frac{x}{1+x^2} = 1/4 \text { iff }$
$4 x = 1+x^2 \text { iff }$
$x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$

Plugging into the quadratic formula, you get

$\alpha = 2 - \sqrt 3$
$\beta = 2 + \sqrt 3$

Observe that $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$.